Can our knowledge about physics and the universe always advance without dealing with axiomatic facts?
By axiomatic facts I mean facts that are so fundamental that they can not be explained by a more fundamental fact, that is, they're not a logical consequence of anything else. When that happens, the best explanation left is a foundationalist (instead of infinitism or coherentism paradigms) one, by assuming they are a self-evident truth that doesn't need or at best will never have a concrete proof for their existence.
I might be wrong in some of them, in the sense that the affirmations themselves might not be true or that they actually have a fundamental explanation, but as far as I know I couldn't find any explanation like that for those facts in physics:

Why does Galilean relativity works for almost everything, except massless particles and EM waves?
Why do macroscopic objects have defined properties but detecting/interacting microscopic objects like a particle changes its intrinsic behavior (double slit, light passing polarizers in series)?
Why is time generally treated as a background parameter in quantum mechanics but not general relativity?
Why does locality works everywhere but not with entangled particles (by Bell's theorem)?
Why is information conserved in most cases but not in black holes?

By thinking like in set theory, that kind of contradiction or mutual exclusion seems to imply that the conflicting laws or rules should be a special or limiting case of a broader law. Starting from that, are we limited to resort to foundationalism when dealing with facts like those above?

Please focus down to a single question.

And since you have received an answer already, please make sure that your focusing does not exclude the answer below.

The axioms you mention are included in theory because they are useful. They lead to effective and more accurate descriptions and predictions.

And as to your #4: even particles that are not entangled violate locality in certain specific manners. For example, think of a particle in a momentum eigenstate. Where is it?

If what you’re after (based on your comment on the top answer) is a unified field theory that describes both QM and GR, so is a lot of the physics community. Such a theory would get around the apparent issues that QM and GR disagree upon, like the nature of time and black-hole information conservation (or deletion). If anyone comes up with a working, consistent, accepted theory, then you (and the rest of the world) will most certainly hear about it, because it would earn that person eternal fame and glory.

Physics, like all of the natural sciences, is based on inductive reasoning. It gathers together a set of facts (observations, measurements, or experimental results about our universe) and then derives laws, principles or axioms that explain these facts. So in physics the facts come before the axioms. This is in contrast to a deductive science such as mathematics or logic, in which the axioms come first and are used to deduce other facts that are consistent with these axioms.
Any question of the form "Why is this theory in physics based on these principles and not some other principles ?" must have the answer "Because these principles explain the at least some of the available facts". If the principles do not explain all of the available facts then this suggests that the theory is incomplete, and its principles need to be amended, enhanced or extended.
Note that an incomplete theory may still be useful - and used often - either because it produces results that are "good enough" in some sense (e.g. we do not make relativistic corrections when calculating the path of a snooker ball because Newtonian mechanics is "good enough") or because we do not yet know how to build a more complete theory (e.g. the tension between general relativity and quantum mechanics). So the answer to a question like "Why do we use this theory in this scenario  but a different theory in another scenario ?" is the pragmatic answer "Because it works".
But any question of the form "Why does our universe behave in accordance with these principles and not some other set of principles ?" is outside of the realm of physics.

I think I should have worded it better, I was trying to find out if it was possible to develop a broader theory that encompasses both QM and GR without addressing these facts, since it seemed almost inevitable to stumble upon one of them. However, as you said, that means that the theory is incomplete, yet still useful.
